# How to create and UITableViewController Subclass that handles the protocols by itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, protocols

Ok, so i'm building a custom TableViewController. The idea is to abstract most of the methods needed to create it.
What i've made is:
LPTableViewController that inherits from UITableViewController, and complies and implements all TableviewControllers methods, so if assign it as a controller class of TableViewController in Storyboard it works OK.
But the real idea is to use it like a custom control, so i would create a "MainTableViewController" class that would be hooked in storyboard and that inherits from LPTableViewController.

My problems come when i need to create a custom protocol for my Class, that would return to the LPTableViewController an array with data to populate the TableView. But i dont know how to implement it in a way that works. Here's what i have:

**LPTreeView.h**

```
@protocol LPTreeViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (NSArray *)treeViewData;
@end

@interface LPTreeView : UITableViewController <LPTreeViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<LPTreeViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**LPTreeView.m**

```
#import "LPTreeView.h"

@implementation LPTreeView


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self populateCurrentData];
}


-(NSArray *)treeViewData {
    return @[];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
...
```

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import "LPTreeView.h"

@interface InheritanceViewController : UIViewController <LPTreeViewDelegate>

@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
@interface InheritanceViewController () 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation InheritanceViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    LPTreeView *treeView = [[LPTreeView alloc] init];
    _tableView.dataSource = treeView;
    _tableView.delegate = treeView;

}

-(NSArray *)treeViewData {
    return @[
             @{@"name": @"Data",
               @"image": @"Image",
               @"subcategories": @[ @"One", @"Two", @"Three" ]},
             @{@"name": @"Data2",
               @"image": @"Image-1",
               @"subcategories": @[ @"One", @"Two", @"Three" ]},
             @{@"name": @"Data3",
               @"image": @"Image-2",
               @"subcategories": @[ @"One", @"Two", @"Three" ]},
             ];
}
```

Whatever i try, my tableview always tries to find the TableViewController obligatory methods inside MainViewController instead of LPTreeView.
THANKS!

Comment: Your preamble mentions wanting to use inheritance, but your mainViewController implementation seems to be using composition.  Can i recommend [this question and answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/263056) from the Programmers Stack Exchange site as a quick comparison of the two methods?

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this all wrong.

1. Rename your `LPTreeView` class to `LPTreeViewController` since it isn't a view.
2. Get rid of the `LPTreeViewDelegate` protocol.
3. Move the declaration for the `- (NSArray *)treeViewData` method to the `LPTreeViewController` class.
4. The `viewDidLoad` method of the `LPTreeViewController` class should call:

   ```
   self.tableView.delegate = self;
   self.tableView.dataSource = self;
   ```
5. Your `InheritanceViewController` class should extend `LPTreeViewController`, not `UIViewController.
6. `InheritanceViewController` should not conform to the protocol or have its own `tableView` property.
7. `viewDidLoad` in `InheritanceViewController` should create `LPTreeView` or set its delegate.

**LPTreeViewController.h**

```
@interface LPTreeViewController : UITableViewController

- (NSArray *)treeViewData;

@end
```

**LPTreeViewController.m**

```
#import "LPTreeViewController.h"

@implementation LPTreeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    [self populateCurrentData];
}

-(NSArray *)treeViewData {
    return @[];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
...
```

**InheritanceViewController.h**

```
#import "LPTreeViewController.h"

@interface InheritanceViewController : LPTreeViewController

@end
```

**InheritanceViewController.m**

```
@implementation InheritanceViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(NSArray *)treeViewData {
    return @[
         @{@"name": @"Data",
           @"image": @"Image",
           @"subcategories": @[ @"One", @"Two", @"Three" ]},
         @{@"name": @"Data2",
           @"image": @"Image-1",
           @"subcategories": @[ @"One", @"Two", @"Three" ]},
         @{@"name": @"Data3",
           @"image": @"Image-2",
           @"subcategories": @[ @"One", @"Two", @"Three" ]},
         ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! It helped me a lot but didnt got where i wanted. The thing is i wanted to make it compatible with a UIViewController that happens to have a TableView inside it, thats why i've been doing the protocols. So i can have for example, a tableView and a image in a single view. Thanks!